# How to list XML nodes that do not contain specific children

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to parse an xml document to find all parent assets as written by people in our company.  The problem I've run into is eliminating all the children. For instance in the snippet below

```
<PAGE ID="ID0001.4">
</PAGE>
<PAGE>
</PAGE>
<PAGE ID="ID0003.1">
    <PAGE>
        <PAGE ID="ID0004">
            <PAGE ID="ID0007.8">
            </PAGE>
        </PAGE>
    </PAGE>
</PAGE>
<PAGE>
    <PAGE>
        <PAGE ID="ID0012.9">
            <PAGE ID="ID0009.2">
            </PAGE>
        </PAGE>
    </PAGE>
</PAGE>
```

I want to return

```
"ID0001.4"
"ID0003.1"
"ID0012.9"
```

and not

```
"ID0004"
"ID0007.8"
"ID0009.2"
```

I started using [`.iter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.iter). But that doesn't maintain a list of parents. So I tried to double `.iter` and remove children which, *really* doesn't work...

I'm assuming I need to write a recursive [`.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) but was really hoping there was a more elegant solution that I'm overlooking.  Recursion of `.findall` would be necessary as I have no way to know how deep the tree goes.

Answer (score -1):

Use the python ElementTree XML API

```
x='''<root><PAGE ID='ID0001.4'>
</PAGE>
<PAGE>
</PAGE>
<PAGE ID="ID0003.1">
<PAGE>
    <PAGE ID="ID0004">
        <PAGE ID="ID0007.8">
        </PAGE>
    </PAGE>
</PAGE>
</PAGE>
<PAGE>
<PAGE>
    <PAGE ID="ID0012.9">
        <PAGE ID='ID0009.2'>
        </PAGE>
    </PAGE>
</PAGE>
</PAGE></root>'''


import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.fromstring(x)
for i in tree.iter('PAGE'):
    if i.attrib;print i.attrib
```

Output:

```
{'ID': 'ID0001.4'}
{'ID': 'ID0003.1'}
{'ID': 'ID0004'}
{'ID': 'ID0007.8'}
{'ID': 'ID0012.9'}
{'ID': 'ID0009.2'}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, I do not want to return "ID0004"
"ID0007.8"
"ID0009.2"